# General solution of different equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the differential equation:
$$
(1+x^3)^2 \frac{dy}{dx} = x^2e^y
$$
Not sure how to do this!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: **Hint:** It is a Separable Equation.

Comment: Im seeming to get : y= -ln(-x^3 /3 - x^12 /12 - x^6 /3 + C) is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just write this as $$\int e^{-y}dy = \int \frac{x^2}{(1+x^3)^2}dx$$ the right hand side of which is easily done with the substitution $t = 1+x^3$.  So then $$-e^{-y} = \frac{-1}{3(1+x^3)}+c$$ where $c$ is the constant of integration.

Comment: Shouldnt it be -e^-y on the left hand side?

Comment: @Ann.  Thanks.  Fixed.